# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file on Selenium after version 4.14.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've been running these kind of code with Selenium before version 4.14.0. For example the code below works with Selenium 4.13.0 without problem. But after 4.14.0 it gives the error as

"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

because of the line:

"driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)"

Why may that be?

My code is as below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Set up the Chrome browser
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

url = "https://www.google.com" 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()

time.sleep(2)

driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver2.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver2.quit()
```

When I change driver.quit() to driver.close() it works but it does not work with driver.quit() as it's before.

Comment: have the same problem, which I'm trying to fix, if I find a solution I'll write here